# Python Download files, but they are empty?

Tags: python, download, urllib2

I'm trying to download file with Python (2.7) using code below - 
But why I get empty file?
Can somebody point me the "leak" - what am I missing?

How to get original file with text inside?

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/splz3vk9pl1tbgz/test.txt?dl=0'
user_agent = 'Mozilla 5.0 (Windows 7; Win64; x64)'
file_name = "test.txt"
u = urllib2.Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent})
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
f.close()
```

Comment: Because you open a file and then immediately close it. Did you mean to write some data in between?

Comment: yes. I want data between
how to implement it?
google search - no love

Comment: All you have to do is search for _python download file_ and there are *loads* of examples. Wouldn't that be easier than asking a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: you didnt read the url, and didnt write to file too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is:

1. never actually sending out the HTTP request; `Request()` just builds a request, `urlopen()` actually sends it;
2. never actually writing anything to the file with `f.write()`, you're just opening a file and immediately closing it.

A full example might look like:

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/splz3vk9pl1tbgz/test.txt?dl=0'
user_agent = 'Mozilla 5.0 (Windows 7; Win64; x64)'
file_name = "test.txt"
u = urllib2.Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent})

# Actually make the request
req = urllib2.urlopen(u)

f = open(file_name, 'wb')

# Read data from the request, and write it to the file
f.write(req.read())

f.close()
```

Comment: thanks to all for you comments and answer/ Hope this improve my google skills